# How to stop intellij from converting my code?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I'm using scala and every time I paste my code it changes the format. I reset the settings but it keeps doing it. I can't find the setting I tried to disable in Smart Keys but still.

What I want to paste

`addItem: "food", "arroz", "arroz.jpg", 300, 1.50;`

What gets pasted

```
addItem //todo: labels is not supported
"food"
"arroz"
"arroz.jpg"
300
1.50
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That doesn't happen to me, but maybe you have "Convert Java code to Scala on copy-paste" and under that "Don't show dialog on paste and automatically convert to Scala code" selected.

Check it out under `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Scala -> Editor`. This is for Mac, but I assume it is something similar if you are using something else.